# VPN Clients only can connect to other machines after ping

Tags: vpn, ping, route, nc, subnets

I have a weird problem. I have an OpenVPN server up and running. When my VPN clients (10.0.0.x) try to connect to another machines (192.168.0.x), they fail (I tried netcat, telnet and SIP). If I perform a ping from the same client (10.0.0.x) to the same machines (192.168.0.x), it works, and suddenly the services (netcat, telnet, sip, etc) also start to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `192.168.0.x` machines behind VPN server, then you should probably add something like that to your OpenVPN server configuration:

`push "route 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0"`

Issue is definitely strange, but my guess is that it is related to absent route between `10.0.0.x`, VPN server and `192.168.0.x`

Comment: Thank you Pavel.
I have the route in VPN conf. The connection isnt completely broken because it works after ping, and thats what is confusing me.